# In R, how do I match markdown list

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to match the following ordered and unordered lists and extract the bullet/list point.

```
library(stringr)
examples <- c(
"* Bullet 1\n* Bullet 2\n* Bullet 3",
"1. Bullet 1\n2. Bullet 2\n3. Bullet 3",
"* This is a test 1\n* This is a test with some *formatting*\n* This is a test with different _formatting_"
)
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Recognize that it's a list programatically
2. Parse each into just the text of the list item

The result would be

```
some_str_fun(example,pattern) # or multiples
"Bullet 1" "Bullet 2" "Bullet 3"
"Bullet 1" "Bullet 2" "Bullet 3"
"This is a test 1" "This is a test with some *formatting*" 
"This is a test with different _formatting_"
```

I've been playing with the following patterns, and str_extract/match but can't seem to find something completely functional

```
[*]+\\s(.*?)[\n]* # for * Bullet X\n
[1-9]+[.]\\s(.*?)[\n]* # for 1. Bullet X\n
```

I've tried a bunch of different iterations on these patters but can't quite seem to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to have a "0": e.g. `10. Bullet`?

Comment: @Frank no I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option.  You can wrap in `unlist` if desired:

```
str_extract_all(examples, "[^*1-9\n ]\\w+( ?[\\w*]+)*")
# or 
#str_extract_all(examples, "[^*1-9\n ]\\w+( ?[a-zA-Z0-9_*]+)*")

#[[1]]
#[1] "Bullet 1" "Bullet 2" "Bullet 3"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "Bullet 1" "Bullet 2" "Bullet 3"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "This is a test 1"                          
#[2] "This is a test with some *formatting*"     
#[3] "This is a test with different _formatting_"
```

There are several other options, particularly if you're not concerned about getting it all in a single regex or single line of code.  Here's one more approach.  The regex is simpler, but you end up with `""`, which requires the additional line:

```
splits <- unlist(str_split(examples, "\n|\\d+\\. |\\* "))
splits[splits != ""]
#[1] "Bullet 1"                                  
#[2] "Bullet 2"                                  
#[3] "Bullet 3"                                  
#[4] "Bullet 1"                                  
#[5] "Bullet 2"                                  
#[6] "Bullet 3"                                  
#[7] "This is a test 1"                          
#[8] "This is a test with some *formatting*"     
#[9] "This is a test with different _formatting_"
```

Comment: What happens to the trailing numbers in the first few bullets?

Comment: The regular expression wrote does not match what you assume it does.

Comment: You're wrapping the initial part inside of a negated character class, you can't use grouping constructs inside of a class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strapply` from the [**gsubfn**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) package to match the entire pattern.

```
library(gsubfn)

examples <- c(
    "* Bullet 1\n* Bullet 2\n* Bullet 3",
    "1. Bullet 1\n2. Bullet 2\n3. Bullet 3",
    "* This is a test 1\n* This is a test with some *formatting*\n* This is a test with different _formatting_"
)

strapply(examples, '(?:\\*|\\d+\\.) *([^\n]+)', c, simplify = c)

# [1] "Bullet 1"                                  
# [2] "Bullet 2"                                  
# [3] "Bullet 3"                                  
# [4] "Bullet 1"                                  
# [5] "Bullet 2"                                  
# [6] "Bullet 3"                                  
# [7] "This is a test 1"                          
# [8] "This is a test with some *formatting*"     
# [9] "This is a test with different _formatting_"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a different approach, but if you render the markdown to HTML you can use some existing extraction methods to do what you want:

```
library(stringr)

examples <- c(
"* Bullet 1\n* Bullet 2\n* Bullet 3",
"1. Bullet 1\n2. Bullet 2\n3. Bullet 3",
"* This is a test 1\n* This is a test with some *formatting*\n* This is a test with different _formatting_"
)

extract_md_list <- function(md_text) {

  require(rvest)
  require(rmarkdown)

  fil_md <- tempfile()
  fil_html <- tempfile()
  writeLines(md_text, con=fil_md)

  render(fil_md, output_format="html_document", output_file=fil_html, quiet=TRUE)

  pg <- html(fil_html)
  ret <- html_nodes(pg, "li") %>% html_text()

  # cleanup
  unlink(fil_md)
  unlink(fil_html)

  return(ret)

}

extract_md_list(examples)

## [1] "Bullet 1"                                
## [2] "Bullet 2"                                
## [3] "Bullet 3"                                
## [4] "Bullet 1"                                
## [5] "Bullet 2"                                
## [6] "Bullet 3"                                
## [7] "This is a test 1"                        
## [8] "This is a test with some formatting"     
## [9] "This is a test with different formatting"
```

Comment: I like this. But I've already coded the rest directly from Rmd (bold italics, plots, inline R).

Comment: there _is_ a reason `pandoc` exists, but if you are heck-bent on regexes, then you shld be able to use element of https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900 to extract what you need. this is fast and clean, though.

Comment: Pandoc can't run R code. Or at least, not them I'm aware of.